# Identifying Tail-Recursion

Tags: racket, tail-recursion

Using Racket, I have written the following function, poly-eval, to compute the value of a polynomial given the coefficients and an integer:

```
(define (poly-eval coeffs x)
(letrec ([helper (lambda (coeffs x y)
    (if (empty? coeffs)
        0
        (+ (helper (cdr coeffs) x (- y 1)) (* (car coeffs) (iexpt x (- y 1))))))])
  (helper (reverse coeffs) x (length coeffs))))
```

From my understanding, this is a tail-recursive solution. Is this correct? Is there any way to manually check and identify a function as tail-recursive?

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning? After that, do the answers to [What is tail recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion) (read more than just the top one) help?

Comment: I believe this to be a tail-recursive function because the final returned value is a call to the recursive function itself.

Comment: Well, it’s not – it’s `(+ … …)`.

Comment: For `(helper ...)` to be in tail position it has to be the tail expression and not an argument to a call. `if` and `cond` forms in tail position makes their consequent and alternative also be in tail position, but not the predicate. Thus the `if` in your example is the tail expression and it makes `0` as well as the `(+ ...)` in tail position. You probably should look at [a-normalization](https://matt.might.net/articles/a-normalization/) and [CPS](https://matt.might.net/articles/cps-conversion/)

Comment: If you're thinking of the very last line in `poly-eval` (which *is* in tail position, but not a recursion), then turn `helper` into a global function and look at it in isolation.

Comment: Use the `Check Syntax` in DrRacket. Examine the arrows showing where the result flows. More in the manual.